# How to find out the definition of the variable MAKE

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Haven't been using `make` for a while. But just got a project from a 10 years old compiler using Ubuntu.

I am looking at the makefile and trying to find out which compiler it is using.
`${MAKE}` is used in the file.
But where can I find out the definition of `MAKE`.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use both the [`info`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html) and [`value`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Value-Function.html) built-in functions inside your makefile:

```
$(info MAKE: $(value MAKE))
```

This will work if `MAKE` is a *[recursively expanded variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html)*, which it is by default. Otherwise, if `MAKE` were a *simply expanded variable*, you will see the expansion that was done at the moment of evaluating `MAKE`'s definition (i.e., the same as `$(MAKE)`).

---

A better approach, which is independent of the flavour of the variable, would be to run `make` with the option `-p` and look at the definition of `MAKE`, e.g.:

```
make -p | grep 'MAKE ='
```

---

You will probably find out that `MAKE` is defined as:

```
MAKE = $(MAKE_COMMAND)
```

and `MAKE_COMMAND`, which is another variable (this time, a simply expanded one), may be in turn defined as:

```
MAKE_COMMAND := make
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it better. I have the compiler and linker, the .exe file. I can just use Eclipse to build the project right? The whole purpose to get a "linux" installed on the computer is to run "make" because make is able to interpret the Makefile. And the Eclipse I installed with C/C++ support is able to interpret the Makefile.

Comment: GNU Make is also available for Windows. Search for **MinGW**.

Comment: Thanks. So it doesn't make sense anymore to install linux (cygwin or WSL) on windows computer just for "make".